# Is there a limit on number of variables under Namespace definition in Jinja?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I am facing this problem of trying to customise the print format in Jinja. I tried to create a lot of variables using the namespace scoping, so that the variables can be used outside a loop.

For example, I tried the following code to insert as customised code in HTML to print format:

```
{% set det = namespace(abbr=’’) %}
{% set det = namespace(DATE=‘01-01-2021’) %}
{% set det = namespace(BA=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(BO=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(CO=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(CR=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(CRAW=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(PH=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(CE=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(CEAW=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(SL=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(RL=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(CPFE=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(CPFR=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(CPFT=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(TP=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(NS=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(count=0) %}
{% set det = namespace(TA=0) %}
{% set det.count = det.count + 1 %}
```

However, I get the following error:

> self.environment.handle_exception()
> File “env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py”, line 925, in handle_exception
> raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
> File “”, line 23, in top-level template code
> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: ‘jinja2.utils.Namespace object’ has no attribute ‘count’

I am rather confused as `det.count` was defined as `0`. I think it could be because I have created too many variables under the namespace that created this error.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with a limit of the the number of variables in a namespace, you just keep on overriding your namespace by reassigning it.

This can be tested with a simpler example:

```
{% set ns = namespace(foo=0) %}
{% set ns = namespace(bar=42) %}
{% set ns.foo = ns.foo + 1 %}
```

Which yields the same message as yours:

> 'jinja2.utils.Namespace object' has no attribute 'foo'

If you want multiple variables defined in you namespace, pass them all, comma separated, to the definition of the namespace:

```
{% set ns = namespace(foo=0, bar=42) %}
{% set ns.foo = ns.foo + 1 %}
```